# How to open multiple tabs on my browser based on the input set of values using Javascript , code added

Tags: javascript

Problem:In my workplace sometimes i have to open multiple tickets that i have to open in order to do data analysis. 
I have the ticket numbers handy with me. And the hyperlink to open the ticket only differs in the ticket number.
How can i automate it , i have do huge analysis for about 4000 tickets, so i really need to automate this stuff.

```
Hyerplink is of the format 

https://oldwebe.company.com/xyz/Ticketnumber.jspx?tNumber=7-12345
```

where 12345 is the ticket number.

So say i have below ticket numbers:
12333
12432
12123

Which means that in  above requirement i should be able to open below hyperlinks each in a separate tab.

```
https://oldwebe.company.com/xyz/Ticketnumber.jspx?tNumber=7-12333
https://oldwebe.company.com/xyz/Ticketnumber.jspx?tNumber=7-12432
https://oldwebe.company.com/xyz/Ticketnumber.jspx?tNumber=7-12123
```

I have to open below links automatically based on the input ticket numbers that i give. So  that input number of tickets  can change , sometimes i should be able to open 10 tickets, sometimes 20 , sometimes 50 and so on.

Note:

1.I dont want to use python because when i try to open the firefox browser from it , i am being asked to reauthenticate again.
So that defeats the purpose of this automation.
Also note that i havent yet written any logic to do that in python either.

2. I am a complete newbie in Javascript and do not have a code to share and say i could write upto this etc. So would really appreciate of community members.
3. I prefer to use Javascript because i am using one small script (in a bookmark) provided by company forum to open web portal based on only 1 input ticket. But if you think it easily doable in any other language which can be input in a bookmark, for which i can give a shortcut key, i am open to that as well.

Below is the slightly redacted version of the script i mentioned i am using currently, :

```
    (
    function()%20
    {
        var%20fvalue=prompt("Search%20Ticket","Ticket");%20if(fvalue!=null){%20if%20((fvalue.indexOf('-')==1)%20&&%20(fvalue.lastIndexOf('-')==1)%20&&%20(!isNaN(fvalue.replace('-'%20,%200))))
            %20{self.window.open('https://oldwebe.company.com/xyz/Ticketnumber.jspx?tNumber='+fvalue).focus()}
        %20else%20if%20
        ((fvalue.indexOf('-')==1)%20&&%20(fvalue.lastIndexOf('-')==1)%20&&%20(fvalue.lastIndexOf('%20')==-1)%20&&%20 (isNaN(fvalue.replace('-'%20,%200))))
        %20{A}
        %20else%20if((fvalue.charAt((fvalue.length)-2)%20==%20'.')%20&&
    (!isNaN(fvalue)))%20{B}%20else%20if((fvalue.indexOf('.')==-1%20)%20&&
    (!isNaN(fvalue)))%20{C}%20}
    }
    )();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you want rightm, you can do something so simple like this

```
for( i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    window.open('URL'+ticketId, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how to do that in Javascript , how would the code look like. if you can give me a little more , would really appreciate . note that ticketID will be different for each iteration and i dont want to enter it manually , maybe read from some csv in my computer. i am not at all good in Javascript so would appreciate any inputs